# jQuery AJAX to ASMX web service works in IE, not in Chrome or FF

Tags: asp.net, ajax, jquery

I have a ASP.NET webforms project in .NET 3.5 running locally on my machine hosting an ASMX web service. The web service works fine when called from Ajax in IE8, however, using Firefox and Chrome do not work.

The jQuery code is:

```
$.post("http://localhost:64284/StockService.asmx/DeleteStock",
    { stockId: '"' + code + '"' });
```

Code is a previous value retrieved from a form element.

This service works fine when invoked from Internet Explorer. It does not work from Chrome or Firefox. I have also tried the $.ajax which doesn't work either.

Firebug shows "OPTIONS DeleteStock" in the Net panel which I find odd as that is the name of the service method. I'd of expected to see POST StockService.asmx however I'm new to jQuery Ajax.

The consuming application is a web forms project, also running on my machine but on another port, but running .NET 4.

Can anyone give any advice? The service is defined as:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class StockService: System.Web.Services.WebService
// ...
    [WebMethod]
    public JimStock[] DeleteStock(string stockId)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Comment: Is the site containing the AJAX call also located on `localhost:64284`? If not you'll need Cross-Domain AJAX (the easiest way to achieve that is using JSONp)

Comment: No, and I thought that might be the issue, so it is port specific? 64284 hosts the web service, 57886 hosts the consuming web app.

When it is deployed both applications will be on the same server but under different DNS names, i.e. service on http://soap and the consumer at http://stockmanagement

Comment: Yes, the port matters.  Use IIS (or easier, IIS Express) to set hosting up the same as you're planning on in production.  For that matter, is there a sound reason why they *must* be in separate projects?  If StockService exists primarily to handle AJAX callbacks from your WebForms project, there's nothing architecturally wrong with it existing in that project, which would eliminate this issue entirely.

Comment: Dave thanks for your feedback. Yes, the web service project exists to interact with other projects. It's just this is the first time it's needed to be called via Ajax. So will being on the same physical server with different DNS entries be problematic? Will JSONp fix the problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As point out by ThiefMaster and stockmanagement point out - the issue was that it was cross domain. Unfortunately, they didn't leave an answer so I had to.