# $.ajax call to asmx Web Service (in the same site) works on IE but fails in FF and Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asmx

First of all, I don't believe my question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912803/jquery-ajax-to-asmx-web-service-works-in-ie-not-in-chrome-or-ff). The calling pages and the asmx web service are in the same web site, at the same hierarchical level, and the pages have permission to access the asmx file.

Now, on to my question.

I've got a Web Site I'm developing that does some long-running processes against a SQL Server. I've decided that the standard ajaxloader.gif is insufficient for my needs, because the tasks can take variable amounts of time (15 seconds to 5+ minutes).

So, I've developed a system of 2 Web Services to handle showing actual progress to the user. The first web service does the work, updating a shared variable in the Service class. The second web service is called every half second or so (sometimes I set it's interval as low as 100ms) and reads the progress values out of the shared variable.

Now, this system works beautifully on IE (I'm working with IE9), but seems to fail completely in FF and Chrome (both on Windows and OS X). It also fails in Safari on OS X.

I've tried to begin learning to debug in non-IE browsers, but I'm struggling there (which might be why I can't figure this out). I set breakpoints in my JavaScript/jQuery code, but they never get triggered. I set "debugger" areas in my JS/jQuery code, and those stop IE, but don't stop FF and Chrome (which I think seems to be "correct" behavior). So, I set breakpoints in my Service code-behind file, and they seem to be triggered about 1 time out of 3. So, it's not failing completely, but it does fail a lot. As I mentioned, it doesn't fail at all on IE. I've tried debugging this in FireBug on FireFox (Windows), but I've been unable to get useful information out of the error code. As far as I can tell, I'm simply getting back an error with ErrorText="error". (Not helpful!)

Here's my jQuery code:

```
function LongRunningProcess() {
    debugger;
    $('#progressBar').show();
    $('#progressLabel').show();
    var b = $('#<%= startDateTextBox.ClientID %>').datepicker("getDate");
    var e = $('#<%= endDateTextBox.ClientID %>').datepicker("getDate");
    var bString = (b.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + b.getDate() + '/' + b.getFullYear();
    var eString = (e.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + e.getDate() + '/' + e.getFullYear();
    var params = '{beginningDateString:"' + bString + '", endingDateString:"' + eString + '"}';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service.asmx/LongRunningProcess",
        data: params,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: Returned,
        error: ShowError
    });
    GetProgress();
}
function GetProgress() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service.asmx/ShowProgress",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: ProgressReturned,
        error: ShowError
    });
}
function Returned(missing) {
    // This code isn't important/doesn't affect my question,
    // but it does exist and catch the return in IE
}
function ProgressReturned(progress) {
    $('#progressBar').progressbar("option", "value", progress.d.Progress);
    $('#progressLabel').html(progress.d.Step + ' (' + progress.d.Progress.toFixed(2) + '%)');
    if (progress.d.Progress < 100) {
        setTimeout(GetProgress, 100);
    } else {
        $('#progressBar').progressbar("option", "value", 0);
        $('#progressLabel').html('Done.');
        $('#progressBar').hide();
        $('#progressLabel').hide();
    }
}
function ShowError(request, error) {
    debugger;
    alert(error);
}
```

I'm new-ish to ASP.NET web programming and very new to JavaScript and jQuery, but I've attempted to do good research and figure out how these things work. Plus, like I said, the above code works beautifully (exactly as I want) in IE9. Also, on non-IE browsers, a breakpoint set on the first line of "Service.asmx/LongRunningProcess" is rarely triggered/met. So, I don't think the code error is in my VB.NET code, which is why I didn't post it. Do I have a syntax error or something?

Comment: IE might be more forgiving when it comes to timing out. Its not usually a good Idea to have a long running web service for this reason. Can you break it up into multiple shorter running web service calls?

Comment: No, plus the errors in the non-IE browsers occur immediately. It doesn't appear to be a timeout issue in any way. Plus, aren't long-running processes one of the very reasons we use ajax in the first place?

Comment: This should help get you started debugging with Firebug - http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel. Look for errors in the console and in the response details in the Net panel. Without an error message, its hard to say what might be the problem here.

Comment: Cau u provide us the error please, I copy your code and create the Methods in a WebService and it works perfectly in IE and FF.

Comment: I'm continuing to do research on this, but I think it may all come down to the need to place `return false;` after my method call in the onclick handler.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I was missing a `return false;` in my `onclick`. Putting that in seems to have resolved all of my issues. What a pain! Question: how should I close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it was simply the "return false;" that I was missing.